# find command with 'regex' match not working

Tags: regex, bash, unix, find

Am trying to do a simple file-name match with this below regex which I tested to be working from this [`page`](https://regex101.com/) for a sample file-name `ABC_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.sha1`

```
ABC_20[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])([0-2][0-3])([0-5][0-9])([0-5][0-9])\.sha1
```

When I couple this in the `-regex` flag of `find` like

```
find . -type f -regex "ABC_20[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])([0-2][0-3])([0-5][0-9])([0-5][0-9])\.sha1"
```

the command is not identifying the file present in the path (e.g `ABC_20161231225950.sha1`). Am aware of many existing regex-types from this [`page`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Base-Name-Patterns), but I realized my type is `posix-extended` and tried as below,

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex 'ABC_20[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])([0-2][0-3])([0-5][0-9])([0-5][0-9])\.sha1'
```

and still no result. I searched around some similar questions of this type, but they were involving giving the wrong regex leading to files not being found. In my case, though the regex is found to be proper. I need to know what am I missing here. Also possibly how to debug non matching issues when using `-regex` in `find`.

Note:- I could do some optimizations over the capturing groups in the regex, but that is not in the scope of the current question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add `.*` at the start of your regex because you will always get something like `./` at start of path

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*ABC_20[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])([0-2][0-3])([0-5][0-9])([0-5][0-9])\.sha1'
```

Comment: Ah! it does work! not sure how did I miss that! But the `./` is the path pre-pended by `find` in this case. Are there better ways to match files than `find` regex?

Comment: `find` is the best tool I know for this job

Comment: So `-regex` and `-iregex` always imply `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end, basically?

Comment: I know this is very late, but just for others, you don't always want to prefix the search with `.*` because that will match anything at the beginning of the name in addition to the `./` prefixed in file paths returned by `find` that @baddger964 noted. For example, if I wanted all files prefixed with `foo.*` in the current dir, if I did `find . -regex ".*foo.*"` that could also match `./barfoo` which isn't right. Sometimes it's better to explicitly write the `./` in your search such as `find . -regex "^\./foo.*"`.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru (or for anyone else who wonders the same question), no, you can still use `^` and `$` as normal. See my answer above. It's just that file paths returned by `find` are prefixed by `./` so you have to take that into account in your searches whether using wildcards or searching that prefix explicitly.